# How do I extract the first part of a url?

Tags: javascript

Given:

```
http://something.com:4567/data/21/28/188
```

How do I get only the following with JavaScript?

```
http://something.com:4567/
```

Comment: Regex matching the first part as a group (up until first backslash not in protocol) Cant think of the syntax. Regexlib.com is helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`window.location.protocol+'//'+window.location.host`